# Debugging Janus using NetBeans

Tags: c, netbeans, webrtc

I'm trying to debug a new [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/) plugin using Netbeans IDE 8.0.1. It hits my breakpoints OK but when trying to step through the code it's jumping all over the place and I'm frequently seeing 'optimized out' when trying to inspect variables. I'm fairly sure this is because the code has been built with optimization enabled.

Assuming this is the problem, how do I rebuild it with optimizations disabled please? I've tried running configure with 'CFLAG=-O0 -g' followed by a clean & build, but I'm still getting the same problem. The Janus configure file has a couple of promising looking environment variables, JANUS_CFLAGS and PLUGINS_CFLAGS. However, when I try to set these to '-O0 -g', clean and make I get a compilation error:

fatal error glib.h: No such file or directory

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I work with janus a ton but I have never tried debugging in Netbeans...I wonder if there is a debug compilation flag...I will look around and see what I can find.

Comment: Ok, after configuring and allowing the Makefile to be generated automatically, I was able to compile without optimization by changing the `CFLAGS = -g -O2` to `CFLAGS = -g -O0` if that will help you any.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent - I will give this a try thanks. Did you try stepping through the code after building this way?

Comment: I know it works with GDB and I have gotten it to work in Eclipse(whose debugger is basically a graphical GDB with some improvements).

Comment: @BenjaminTrent - Setting the debug flags through Netbeans did the trick thanks, it's no longer jumping around when stepping through the code. I don't know why it didn't work when running configure from the command line. (If you'd like to add this as an answer I'll accept it.) Thanks for you assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the compilation from the make file(not from the command line), it should work to make the non-optimamized.

Specifically, the line `CFLAGS = -g -O2` should be changed to `CFLAGS = -g -O0`. I know this works with GDB(and consequently eclipse) and SHOULD work with any other debugger.